# Groups modulus operaation

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Define in $G= Mod 13 - {1}$ in operation $*$  for  $x * y = xy - x - y + 2$. Sum and products Addition  are in mod 13. Calculate 3³**

$ 3³= 3*3*3$

$=3*3$

$= 3(3)- 3 - 3 + 2$

$= 2$

$= 2*3$

$= 2(3)- 2 - 3 + 2$

$**=3** $
Is my final answer correct?

Comment: $3(3) - 3 - 3 + 2 \neq 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3* 3* 3=(3* 3)* 3=(3^2-3-3+2)*3=5* 3=$$

$$=5\cdot 3-5-3+2=9$$

Comment: Just being super nitpicky here. If you say $3^2$ instead of $3(3)$ it could be unclear whether you mean $3^2$ in $G$ or in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @genisage, as clear as the OP wrote $\;xy\;$ meaning, apparently, the usual multiplication modulo $\;13\;$ ...anyway, *not* in $\;\Bbb N\;$ :)